# save image in gallary and get file path android

Tags: android, url, gallery

I am new to Android. I want to save an `image` in gallery from `URL` and get file name and path of saved image. So i can open it with `onclick` in gallery.
I tried many solution but I couldn't find proper way to get saved `file path`.

All i want to do is open an image in gallery form `URL` on `onclick`.

my code

```
   activity_edit_profile_basic_imageview_profile_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                galleryAddPic();

            }
        });
```

and

```
    private void galleryAddPic() {
     String fileName = intentProfilePic.substring(intentProfilePic.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
     Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
     File f = new File(intentProfilePic);
     Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
     mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
     this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
     showImage(fileName);
   }
```

and

```
   public void showImage(String fileName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" +"/sdcard/"+fileName ), "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
   }
```

Even i don't know i am doing in right way or wrong.

When i click on imageview my app crashes and error says...

```
 android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///sdcard/4f5eac461a2a75431d392dd71ffebf97.jpg exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

i know i it is wrong path. so i want to know that how to get file path and also save image. and again open it with onclink using filepath. I also don't know whether it saves file or not.

Comment: you are using Nought device which needs FileProvider to access images

Comment: @DivyeshPatel what should i do to open image in gallaery. tell me more about it

Comment: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en

Comment: Guys before u vote it negative u should tell the reason so i could made changes.

Comment: @DivyeshPatel could u be more specific about the problem. i understand the concept but dont know how to use it

Comment: thnkx @DivyeshPatel could u tell me to how to get file path of saved image

Comment: when you save image in storage you saved it with some name. use that name to get image

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/FOLDER/" + a + ".jpg"

Comment: it showing blank black page....like it can not find pic....even i am not sure that my code save image sucessful...could u loot at my code above

Comment: from where you save image ?

Comment: using url like http\\: .....filename.jpg

Comment: wait i post code to fetch image from url and save to gallery

Comment: thnkx....what is `a` and `folder` in ur comment

Comment: that is where you save file and a is name of file

Comment: its too much confusing could to post me code for save image and open it onclick

Comment: wait .....i post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your targetSdkVersion is 24 or higher, we have to use FileProvider class to give access to the particular file or folder to make them accessible for other apps.

Steps to replace file:// uri with content:// uri:

Add this to your manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...
<application
...
<provider
android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
android:exported="false"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
</application>
</manifest>
```

then create a provider_paths.xml file in xml folder under res folder. Folder may be needed to create if it doesn't exist. The content of the file is shown below. It describes that we would like to share access to the External Storage at root folder (path=".") with the name external_files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

The final step is to change the line of code below in

```
Uri photoURI = Uri.fromFile(createImageFile());
```

to

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", createImageFile());
```

Comment: I dont know where to use createImageFile() method

Comment: This link will help you https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en

Answer (score 0):

use this:

start AsynchTask :

```
DownloadSelctedIMG d = new DownloadSelctedIMG();
        d.execute();
```

Now AsynchTask Class:

```
class DownloadSelctedIMG extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

        String ImgPath = "";       

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = new ProgressDialog(ReferActivity.this);
            loading.setMessage("Please Wait..");
            loading.setCancelable(false);
            loading.show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            File f = new File("IMAGE_URL");
            String filename = "image_name.jpg";
            File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/FOLDER/"
            );                            

            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
            ImgPath = wallpaperDirectory.getPath()+ filename;

            String myu_recivedimage = "IMAGE_URL";
            int count;
            try {
                URL myurl = new URL(myu_recivedimage);
                URLConnection conection = myurl.openConnection();

                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
                conection.connect();
                int filelength = conection.getContentLength();
                InputStream inpit = new BufferedInputStream(myurl.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(ImgPath);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = inpit.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                inpit.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (loading != null && loading.isShowing()) {
                loading.dismiss();
            }
            try {


                /*--- SAVED IMAGE PATH--ImgPath   ---------*/

                    File file = new File(ImgPath);





            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

For open image in Gallery:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
                                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                                        new File(ImgPath));


            intent.setDataAndType(photoURI, "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: can u tell me where to use createImageFile() method. I havent use it in my code and also in ur comment.

Comment: where is createImageFile. i can not find

Comment: u told earlier to open image in gallery for `n` version  
 [inthecheesefactory.com/blog/…]

Comment: in above code you have image Path (ImgPath). use that path to open image and show it.

Comment: i am doing this... `File file = new File(ImgPath);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://" +file ), "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);`

Comment: check saved image from default file manager whether it saved or not. and try with file provider to show image in nought devices

Comment: yes image is saved but it still shows balck screen. and i add provider in manifies and add xml but dont know aboout createImageFile().

Comment: createImageFile is just method that return saved image FILE object. is your image url is work in browser?

Comment: yes.....image is saved in file manager but it is now showing in gallery

Comment: try with other device you have